# How to get xml-node with attributes and text content as child at same time with php-soap?

Tags: php, xml, soap

Trying to generate an xml-request for external webservice using php-soap.

By service's api I should pass attributes and text value of node:

```
<Volume type="I" determiningMethod="N">192</Volume>
```

How to do that?

When I pass assoc-array like this:

```
Volume => [type=>"I",determiningMethod=>"N"]
```

I get:

```
<Volume type="I" determiningMethod="N"/>
```

And, of course, if I try this

```
Volume => 192
```

I get:

```
<Volume>192</Volume>
```

But I need both

Comment: Hi sholkyman,
if you want to help others to help you :) it would be useful to include some more code, at least the function call and maybe the wdsl, even just the definition of Volume ...




Php is not my main focus atm, have you checked the [SoapParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapparam.soapparam.php) class ?

Comment: thanks, one of the comments on doс-page of SoapParam is the key

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @giulp for pointing to SoapParam.

According to [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapparam.soapparam.php#114146):

if you need a string like this:

```
<Volume type="I" determiningMethod="N">192</Volume>
```

You should pass array like this:

```
Volume => ['_' => 192, 'type'=>'I', 'determiningMethod'=>'N']
```